# How to change a property of the URP asset via Script in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, urp

I want to change the Render Scale value via code. I don't want to create multiple assets just to change that but if there isn't other way I would also appreciate help on that. There is almost no documentation about this, everything seems outdated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new instance of URP to edit its properties :

```
UniversalRenderPipelineAsset asset = new UniversalRenderPipelineAsset();
asset.renderScale = 0.1f;
GraphicsSettings.renderPipelineAsset = asset;
```

### **How to check the script:**

You can check the default contents of `UniversalRenderPipelineAsset` by creating a new URP Pipeline Asset; then in the inspector, click the Gear icon on the top right corner and click "Edit Script". This will really help you.

## Edit:

As @derHugo said, you can directly edit its properties using `var`.

```
var urpAsset = (UniversalRenderPipelineAsset)GraphicsSettings.renderPipelineAsset;
urpAsset.renderScale = 0.1f;
```

Comment: Eh no ... you can as well simply reference the existing asset ...

Comment: True, thank you both! What I was missing was the class "UniversalRenderPipelineAsset". Couldn't find it.

Comment: The Edit version works fine for me. Thanks